# How Do Small Businesses e.g Pizza Shop Receive Orders from e-commerce website

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, shopping-cart

Lets say I build a website for example using wordpress and my website contains a shopping cart where users place an order for pizza. How exactly does the pizza shop receive the order? I see shops with small machines that instantly receive the order and have capability of printing the order even though they don't have internet in the shop. What is the complete process? i.e. how is the website linked to this machine? How does it work with or without internet? What needs to be done at the website end and at the shop end?

I hope I made it clear. If someone can point me to reading material or can summarize it that would be great.

UPDATE: Just-eat type of machine (JCT box): "The box does not even need an internet connection nor a dedicated phone line! It works wirelessly and only needs electricity" - but Just eat is a big fish I can't afford something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "they don't have internet in the shop".. are you sure about that? being connected can come from cell towers and get ready for it.. phone lines.

Comment: Why is this question being down voted? Please explain so I can amend or rephrase otherwise I won't know. Thanks

Comment: @ergonaut I am sure they don't have internet provider. They do have a phone line. This is what I need explanation for. How does this whole system work?

Comment: why don't you just ask them?

Comment: The down vote will be because the question is off topic. It isn't about programming, it's a general question which is very broad and likely to attract opinion based answers. Also you've asked to be pointed to external resources (ie reading material). And any answer that covered it would need to be pretty big and involved. Hope that helps!

Comment: Email to Fax is the most obvious solution. So you send the pizza order to an email address, which is picked up by the software and faxed out. but most locations can get email, so look up email to print software. so the business is not having to check their email, it happens automatically.